# Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() Not reload in IE only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to redirect page on previous page when i click on currency menu. In this menu set selected currency in cookies and redirect to `Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()` so Request page automatic read cookies and apply currency.
Here is my code

```
    public ActionResult Index(string currency)
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Cookie");

        cookie.Values["CODE"] = currency;
        cookie.Values["sym"] = Currencies[currency];
        cookie.Values["Name"] = CurrenciesName[currency];
        string currencyname = GetCurrencySymbol(currency);
        this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        //return RedirectToRoute(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }`
```

for example page1 have some item with amount in USD now user change currency then i send request to `CurrencyController` with  above Action then return to same page1.

Above code working fine in all browsers but not working in IE 11.
give me some idea where I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you should never rely on `UrlReferrer`. Its value comes from an HTTP header that is not guaranteed to be sent, and even if it *is* sent, it can be tampered with. By using it in the way you are, you're opening yourself up to CSRF and man-in-middle attacks.

The correct way to do something like this is to pass along the URL you want to return to. For example, if a user is on a URL like `/foo/` and then clicks a link where you want to redirect them back to `/foo/` afterwards, then the URL of the link should be something like: `/bar/?returnUrl=/foo/`.

Then, the action responding to `/bar/` would do something like:

```
public ActionResult Bar(string returnUrl)
{
    // do something

    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    // redirect to default
}
```

The `Url.IsLocalUrl` check is to make sure that the return URL is a path on the current site, again, to prevent malicious attacks.